# Should we shorten the "soprano-recorder" tag to "recorder"?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag, "soprano-recorder" seems too specific. Only two questions with this tag are specific to the soprano recorder. The rest of the questions under that tag are not specific to the soprano recorder. It seems the tag should be shortened to "recorder". Is there any reason tag currently stands as "soprano-recorder"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the first question created was [soprano-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soprano-recorder)-specific, and all of the following questions went with it. The other questions should probably be retagged [recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recorder). Separate tags are not particularly useful now, but would be when more questions are asked specifically in regard to the alto, bass, contrabass recorders.

Comment: Would we re-tag the existing non-soprano-specific ones to the recorder tag, or just leave it for future questions?

Comment: Now that I have a Tenor recorder (courtesy of SE :D), should I go ahead and create the [recorder] tag for a question I have about the tenor? The question is tenor-specific. Or should I create a [tenor-recorder] tag?

Comment: I bet years will pass by before separate tags are needed. We could as well go along the [tag:recorder] tag alone :)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment:

- the tag [recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recorder) has 80 questions,

the more specific tags:

- [soprano-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soprano-recorder) has 9,
- and [alto-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alto-recorder) only 6.

Some questions with the more specific tags have a combination (and 1 has all three tags).

Curiously, there is a link on the [recorder's tag info page](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/recorder/info) to:

- [tenor-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenor-recorder) with 0 questions.

---

The soprano/descant recorder is only different from the alto/treble recorder in that the alto is larger, and it is pitched in F rather than C.  Sure these *are* different instruments, but they aren't *different enough* to warrant their own tags.

Similarly, sopranino recorder, tenor recorder, bass recorder, contrabass recorder, etc. don't need their own tags.  I do not see any value in the more specific tags, and agree that these should be merged into the more general tag: [recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recorder).

By analogy, there are 152 questions with the tag: [saxophone](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saxophone), and there isn't (nor is there a need for) more specific tags: soprano saxophone, alto saxophone, tenor saxophone, baritone saxophone, etc.

---

When this question: [Tag Synonyms Proposals Repository!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/tag-synonyms-proposals-repository)
appeared I suggested the merge:

> - [alto-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alto-recorder), [soprano-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soprano-recorder) --> [recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recorder)

which received 3 upvotes.  But only responses to that post with 5 or more upvotes got acted upon.

I've since suggested these merges on the [Tag Synonyms](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) page.