# Remove a tag synonym I suggest, that is still pending approval

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

About 2 years ago, I proposed a tag synonym for [recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recorder) and [alto-recorder](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alto-recorder).

I was new to [Tag Synonyms](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), and accidentally got the proposal the wrong way around.  But unfortunately, pending synonyms can't be un-proposed.

Apparently nobody uses tag synonyms anymore (it's basically a hidden feature); it still hasn't got *any* votes (positive or negative).  Please down-vote this suggestion out of existence (it will only take 2 votes).  If you have 2.5k rep you can do this here:
[Tags Synonyms pending approval](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested)

---

I still want these tags to be synonymised, but the other way around.

##### Related:

- [Tag Synonyms Proposals Repository!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/tag-synonyms-proposals-repository)
- [Should we shorten the "soprano-recorder" tag to "recorder"?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/should-we-shorten-the-soprano-recorder-tag-to-recorder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done

Happy for you to propose the synonym the other way round if you still think it is needed.